# Permission denied in colab

Tags: permissions, stockfish

I want to use stockfish in my colab notebook.
I first tried with the `chess.engine.SimpleEngine.popen_uci()` command, which seems to be outdated, since `module 'chess.engine' has no attribute 'SimpleEngine'`

So I tried with stockfish itself:

```
from stockfish import Stockfish

stockfish = Stockfish('/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/stockfish')
```

Here I always get the error:

> Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/stockfish'

I googled for it and came up with some good tries:

I tried with `!chmod +x '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/stockfish'` which compiled, but didn't resolved the problem, and `!chmod +x 'stockfish'`, which didn't find the folder.

So how exactly do I give permission to use the stockfish folder?

Comment: Your Stockfish path must be an executable, not a package.

Comment: If the folder has `__main__.py` inside it, it can be run using the python command: `python3 /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/stockfish`. There is no other way to run a python module folder (as far as I know). Are you sure that plain old `stockfish` is not installed on your device? If it is, you can run the stockfish engine from the terminal using the `stockfish` command. Usually these chess engines have executables in `/usr/share/games`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the **os.setuid** to 0 like this code below:

```
! wget https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-7.9.2-linux-x86_64.tar.gz -q
! tar -xzf elasticsearch-7.9.2-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
! chown -R daemon:daemon elasticsearch-7.9.2

import os
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
es_server = Popen(['elasticsearch-7.9.2/bin/elasticsearch'],
                   stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT,
                   preexec_fn=lambda: os.setuid(0)  # as daemon
                  )
# wait until ES has started
! sleep 30
```